# Problema al iniciar (run) mi app, en Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Cuando doy para `run` mi `app` me aparece eso **(Lo hago por USB)**:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 30140
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3114)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.view.ViewPager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myfirstapp-SiksX3nzgOgIJ5y6HQY9FQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.myfirstapp-SiksX3nzgOgIJ5y6HQY9FQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3094)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
```

Comment: Agrega tu build.gradle por favor! @Mikhael

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo al LogCat:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9:
>   Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.support.v4.view.ViewPager"

Si en tu `build.gradle`,  estas usando la dependencia :

```
 implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

debes definir en tus layout el ViewPager con la clase `androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager` , ejemplo:

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```